# Pydantic: Get all optional fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, pydantic

I have a pydantic model that looks like: (Using python 3.7)

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class Foo(BaseModel): 
    a: int 
    b: Optional[int]
    c: Optional[int]
```

I want to fetch all field-names that are Optional (in this case: b & c)
I believe I can use the introspect library for this but I'm not sure how to go about checking for the OPTIONAL type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for the `inspect` module. Here is how you check if a type is a union with `None`.

### Python `>=3.10`

```py
from types import NoneType, UnionType
from typing import Any, Union, get_args, get_origin


def is_none_union(type_: Any) -> bool:
    return get_origin(type_) in (Union, UnionType) and NoneType in get_args(type_)
```

### Python `>=3.8`, `<3.10`

```py
from typing import Any, Union, get_args, get_origin

NoneType = type(None)


def is_none_union(type_: Any) -> bool:
    return get_origin(type_) is Union and NoneType in get_args(type_)
```

### Python `3.7`

```py
from typing import Any, Optional, Tuple, Type, Union

NoneType = type(None)


def get_args(type_: Any) -> Tuple[Any, ...]:
    try:
        return type_.__args__
    except AttributeError:
        return ()


def get_origin(type_: Any) -> Optional[Type]:
    try:
        return type_.__origin__
    except AttributeError:
        return None


def is_none_union(type_: Any) -> bool:
    return get_origin(type_) is Union and NoneType in get_args(type_)
```

---

Every model has a `__fields__` class attribute that holds information about all the model fields. So a generator function that takes a model as argument and yields fields that are of a union type with `None` could look like the following.

### Python `>=3.9`

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator

from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.fields import ModelField

# ... import is_none_union


def optional_fields(model: type[BaseModel]) -> Iterator[ModelField]:
    for field in model.__fields__.values():
        if is_none_union(field.annotation):
            yield field
```

### Python `<3.9`

```py
from typing import Iterator, Type

from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.fields import ModelField

# ... import import is_none_union


def optional_fields(model: Type[BaseModel]) -> Iterator[ModelField]:
    for field in model.__fields__.values():
        if is_none_union(field.annotation):
            yield field
```

---

### Demo

```py
from typing import Optional, Union

from pydantic import BaseModel

# ... import optional_fields


class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[int]
    c: Union[int, None]
    # c: int | None  # Python 3.10


print([field.name for field in optional_fields(Foo)])
```

Output: `['b', 'c']`

---

### Full Python `3.7` code

```py
from typing import Any, Iterator, Optional, Tuple, Type, Union

from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.fields import ModelField

NoneType = type(None)


def get_args(type_: Any) -> Tuple[Any, ...]:
    try:
        return type_.__args__
    except AttributeError:
        return ()


def get_origin(type_: Any) -> Optional[Type]:
    try:
        return type_.__origin__
    except AttributeError:
        return None


def is_none_union(type_: Any) -> bool:
    return get_origin(type_) is Union and NoneType in get_args(type_)


def optional_fields(model: Type[BaseModel]) -> Iterator[ModelField]:
    for field in model.__fields__.values():
        if is_none_union(field.annotation):
            yield field


class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[int]
    c: Union[int, None]


print([field.name for field in optional_fields(Foo)])
```

### Full Python `>=3.10` code

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator
from types import NoneType, UnionType
from typing import Any, Optional, Union, get_args, get_origin

from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.fields import ModelField


def is_none_union(type_: Any) -> bool:
    return get_origin(type_) in (Union, UnionType) and NoneType in get_args(type_)


def optional_fields(model: type[BaseModel]) -> Iterator[ModelField]:
    for field in model.__fields__.values():
        if is_none_union(field.annotation):
            yield field


class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[int]
    c: int | None


print([field.name for field in optional_fields(Foo)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Pydantic fields have a function `is_required` that can be used to determine if a field is optional. The code below will get the optional fields for class `Foo`

```py
[k for k,v in Foo.model_fields.items() if not v.is_required()]
```